# Cant send a variable length header to server

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

Im currently trying to build computer monitoring software for a school.
I can currently press monitor and all devices that are connected to my server start screensharing.

It sends the image as bytes with a small header saying its starting a remote desktop stream."rdmstrea" The server knows that the first 16 bytes of the packet is going to contain the header.

However i need to send some sort  of system identifier inside that packet as when they're screensharing I have no idea who is who.

I've been trying to send a command like "rdmstea§" + Dns.GetHostName();

So there is some sort of identification.

However because the sever doesn't know how long the header could be it can't properly cut the header away from the packet and just gather the image data.

Below are some examples of code for when the client sends the command and what the server receives.

CLIENT:

```
public static void SendMultiScreen(byte[] img)
{
    try
    {

        //string command = ("rdmstream§" + Dns.GetHostName()); //This is what I want to add.
        byte[] send = new byte[img.Length + 16]; //Create a new buffer to send to the server
        byte[] header = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("rdmstrea"); //Get the bytes of the header
        Buffer.BlockCopy(header, 0, send, 0, header.Length); //Copy the header to the main buffer
        fps = 800;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(img, 0, send, header.Length, img.Length); //Copy the image to the main buffer

        _clientSocket.Send(send, 0, send.Length, SocketFlags.None); //Send the image to the server


    }
    catch (Exception e) //Something went wrong
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Ended");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            isDisconnect = true; //Disconnect from server

        }
        catch (Exception exc) //Something went really wrong
        {
            //Restart the application
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to send Screen  original ERROR : " + exc.Message);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Application.Restart();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

SERVER:

```
try //Try
{
    string header = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuf, 0, 8 * 2); //Get the header of the message

    if (header == "rdmstrea") //If it's a remote desktop stream
    {

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) //Declare the new memory stream
        {
            stream.Write(recBuf, 8 * 2, recBuf.Length - 8 * 2); //Copy the data from the buffer, to the memory stream
                                                                //Console.WriteLine("multiRecv Length: " + recBuf.Length);
            Bitmap deskimage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream); //Create a bitmap image from the memory stream
            if (resdataav == 0) //If resolution data is not set
            {
                resx = deskimage.Width; //Set the resolution width to the image width
                resy = deskimage.Height; //Set the resolution height to the image height
                resdataav = 1; //The resolution data is set now
            }
            SetImage(deskimage); //Set the image of the remote desktop
            Array.Clear(recBuf, 0, received); //Clear the buffer
            ignoreFlag = true; //Set the ignore flag

            GC.Collect(); //Call the garbage collector
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(5000);
        }
```

All Seems a little confusing but basically, because when programming the client i wanted the header to be a fixed variable I told to server to check 16 bytes into the packet "8 * 2". So How is the server going to check for where the header ends and starts if the header length is going to be different each time?

Comment: The first options that spring to mind are either use an object that has the info you need, and use binary serialization/deserialization, or the simplest one is to just have a fixed length for the identifier (say 100 chars) and pad it to that length on the client, and trim it on the server.

Comment: Incidentally, just have a global var somewhere that you can use for buffer size, rather than having `8 * 2` all over the place ;)

Comment: @Archer Ill give setting the buffer to 100 chars and see how that works, and I send multiple commands to my server that are all different length so i would have just the same amount of variables than i would 8*2 xD thanks for the help though bud!

Comment: No worries - good luck :)